# the given path's format is not supported when clicking save on view that has an attachment

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis-7.5

I have the following code which works fine on my computer both when running from local iis (7.5) or visual studio (iis express). when i publish this code to my client's computer, it throws an error about `the given path's format is not supported`. i have given every user full permissions, ensured the apppool has full permissions and not sure what else to do. the client's computer has IIS 7.5, on windows 7 home edition with no windows authentication and therefore using anonymous authentication. i am using sqlite as a database and entity framework as an ORM.

```
public ActionResult Register(RegisterViewModel model, HttpPostedFileBase uploadFile)
    {

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (model != null)
            {
                var obj = new tblUser()
                {
                    FirstName = model.FirstName,
                    LastName = model.LastName,
                    Title = model.Title,
                    Address = model.Address,
                    Suburb = model.Suburb,
                    HomePhone = model.HomePhone,
                    Mobile = model.Mobile,
                    Email = model.Email,
                    EmergencyName = model.EmergencyContactName,
                    EmergencyPhone = model.EmergencyContactPhone,
                    EmergencyEmail = model.EmergencyContactEmail,
                    EmergencyRelation = model.EmergencyContactRelation,
                    DrivingLicenceExpiryDate = model.DrivingLicenceExpiryDate,
                    DrivingLicenceNo = model.DrivingLicenceNo,
                    DateofBirth = model.DateofBirth,
                    Notes = model.Notes
                };


                if (uploadFile != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(uploadFile.FileName))
                {
                    uploadFile.SaveAs(System.IO.Path.Combine(Server.MapPath($@"~\Content\Images\{uploadFile.FileName}")));
                    obj.ScannedImageLocation = System.IO.Path.Combine($@"~\Content\Images\{uploadFile.FileName}");
                }
                db.tblUsers.Add(obj);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
        }
        ViewBag.Titles = Reload();
        return View(model);
    }
```

Comment: Can you debug and see what actual path is being passed into the SaveAs method? Also post a stack trace of the exception thrown.

Comment: that is an issue because it's client's pc, they don't have visual studio and i don't have the authority to really install it there and that's where i am perplexed on where to start looking.

Comment: You could add some logging to start with, log the full path before you pass it to the SaveAs method. And use a try catch block to log the exception and stack trace.

Comment: yes i will do that

Answer (score 0):

In the following lines you are using C# 6.0 shorthand for string.Format:

```
                uploadFile.SaveAs(System.IO.Path.Combine(Server.MapPath($@"~\Content\Images\{uploadFile.FileName}")));
                obj.ScannedImageLocation = System.IO.Path.Combine($@"~\Content\Images\{uploadFile.FileName}");
```

The error you are getting suggests it could be ignoring the format and taking the string literally, I am wondering if this is because the client's PC does not have the right version of the .Net framework installed?

Comment: The C# 6 features are not dependant on .NET version, it's just compiled into "normal" code when you build, likely using string.Format under the hood.

Comment: i am not sure who marked your answer as negative but it's still a useful troubleshooting step even if it results in string.format. i will upvote it.

Comment: I down voted because it does not answer the question and it is incorrect.

Comment: @mbrdev I had exactly the same thought and am very tempted to remove the answer, I just want him to at least check the .Net version first, as I can't think of another explanation, can you?

Comment: @Justin Harvey until the OP posts more information it's not worth speculating over. The .NET framework version is not going to generate an error like that so I highly doubt it has anything to do with it, what it will be is the path being passed into the SaveAs method is in an invalid format but until we see what the actual path being passed is there's little we can do to help.